# Como funciona a semântica/indexação com o AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, web-crawler, semântica

Sempre me pergunto, o AngularJS é um framework que esta sendo usado constantemente.

Mas eu tenho uma dúvida sobre como funciona ele para os **crawlers** (exemplo googlebot).

Eles chegam a executar o javascript e interpretar o código para obter as informações e mostrar o site desenvolvido sobre a plataforma?

> É que com o angular o HTML teoricamente não tem informação "ainda", primeiro é necessário acionar os controllers e tal.

A pergunta é: Como funciona a semântica/indexação com o Angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[De acordo com este post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), o crawler do Google renderiza páginas que possuem Javascript e navega pelos estados listados.

Partes interessantes do post (tradução livre):

> [...] decidimos tentar interpretar páginas por execução do JavaScript. É difícil fazer isso em grande escala, mas decidimos que vale a pena. [...] Nos últimos meses, o nosso sistema de indexação vem servindo um grande número de páginas da web da maneira como um usuário comum as veria com JavaScript stivado.
>
> Se recursos como JavaScript ou CSS em arquivos separados são bloqueados (digamos, com `robots.txt`) de maneira que Googlebot não pode recuperá-los, os nosso sistema de indexação não será capaz de ver o seu site como um usuário comum.
>
> Recomendamos permitir ao Googlebot recuperar seu JavaScript e CSS para que o seu conteúdo pode ser melhor indexado.

Recomendações para Ajax/JS [podem ser encontradas neste link](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot).

Se você deseja servir o conteúdo de aplicações Angular para crawlers que não suportam o mesmo tipo de funcionalidade, você precisa pré-renderizar o conteúdo. Serviços como o [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) se destinam exatamente a isto.

Comment: Legal, então ele interpreta meu código para poder obter resultados.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Exato. Não encontrei documentação similar para o Bing, entretanto, então assuma que o serviço da MS não consegue interpretar conteúdo dinâmico.

Comment: Obrigado, estava com receio de fazer algo que depois o Google não conseguisse entender.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro pra mim. O crawler vai renderizar a página toda primeiramente e depois iniciar a leitura das metas tag?
Outra dúvida que surgiu é será que os crawlers de redes sociais se comportam de mesmo modo ?

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers (exemplo googlebot) utilizão leitura de texto puro, ou seja, primeiro eles validam meta tags, depois comentários, depois eles removem toda codificação e então lêem o texto todo sem código. Motivo: Aumentar a velocidade de processamento e reduzir erros por ter campos que ocultam, ou possui nodes (nodulos) que são removidos durante a execução. Os Crawlers não executam qualquer tipo de tecnologia (Browser), apenas lêem o arquivo. O Angular não deixa de ser um Javascript como qualquer outro, por essa razão seus elementos são ignorados.
***Apenas itens relevantes para SEO (Otimização) são levados em questão em sua indexação.***

Parte da minha explicação você encontra neste artigo do Google
[Understanding Web Pages Better](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)

*Para entender melhor o processo de visualização de texto puro, faça um requesição da pagina em questão por CURL, Lynx que são tecnologicas comumente utilizadas pelos Crawlers.*

Para uma melhor indexação recomenda-se criar **robots.txt** e **sitemaps XML**.

Comment: A renderização de imagem do Google bot é para exibir para os usuários os itens que o mesmo consegue enxergar, não é utilizada para indexação e/ou execução de conteúdos (Browser). Como diz no proprio site do Google é apenas uma visualização para o usuário https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Uma dica que posso te dar é, faça o curso que eles oferecem, é rápido e fácil, você vai entender melhor como funciona a semântica:

http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o -1, mas entendo a razão - o OP está perguntando a respeito de semântica de SEO, não da linguagem.